# control increment in for loop Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python so please excuse me if this is a very obvious questions, 
how do I write a statement like this in Python

```
for (int i=p*2; i<=n; i += p)
for i in range(p*2, n)
```

but then how does it increment?

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in range(p*2, n + 1, p): # range(inclusive start, non inclusive end, step)
```

Answer (score 4):

`range` generates a sequence of numbers - a range. For example, `range(0,5)` is equivalent to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. It's signature is `range(start, stop, stride)`, which in `C` would be

```
for (int i=start; i<stop; i+=stride)
```

So you should iterate as

```
for i in range(p*2, n+1, p):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

if you look up the range function you will notice that it actually can take three arguments. The third value is the amount to increment by, which is 1 by default. Just change to

```
range(p*2, n, p)
```